# Would I provide client with an initial comp for magazine design?

Tags: client-relations, freelance, design-process

I am new to freelance design and would love some advice on how to deal with a magazine design project. I will be designing a magazine for a client. Would I provide them with some kind of initial comp to determine the style and get approval? If there are any magazine designers reading this that are willing to share their process of dealing with the client, I would be so grateful! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you creating a magazine from scratch or has this magazine been made before?

Comment: I am creating it from scratch.

Comment: Providing an initial comp makes sense, especially if you're also creating the branding for the magazine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

There's **A LOT** which goes into a "magazine" -- branding, ad space, articles, etc -- I don't think a *viable* comp can be created until these have been ironed out.

One would *certainly* comp the **cover** to show some *branding* ideas.

However, beyond that spending time on a full magazine comp is pointless until you know the ad space, articles, etc and can work out page counts.

Generally one settles branding and overall style. Then waits for content collection. Once content is ready (ads space determined, articles written, etc), *then* you layout the initial edition and provide a comp for it. Subsequent editions use the premier issue as a roadmap to know how much content is necessary.

---

In short.. comp for ***branding*** but you can't comp much else until you know what's needed. i.e. you can't bake a cake until you know the ingredients.

(I suppose page count is more irrelevant if it's for digital delivery only).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Very helpful information!